# Is it possible to have Thick white ink for printers?

Tags: print-design

Is the White ink that is available in the market are all transparent ink?
I want a a opaque (thick) white ink for printing. is that possible?

Comment: It's possible. But not for home/office use. If you have a commercial press, you can purchase white inks. If you are silk screening, you can purchase white inks.

Answer (score 4):

There are commercial inks that you would need a business licence and tax form to obtain.  Since you may be using it for home use you would typically be getting a water based ink.  The best option for you may be going to Hobby Lobby.  They do have "do it yourself" home screening kits.  [Example here](http://shop.hobbylobby.com/search/?keyword=screen%20printing&perpage=12&match=AND&F_Sort=2) and white [here](http://shop.hobbylobby.com/products/speedball-white-fabric-screen-printing-ink-496232/) From experience they are typically not transparent BUT you can dilute them to be transparent.

EDIT:

If you are printing on a dark garment, such as black, it is common to make two passes with white for best quality.  Note that if also printing on dark garments its a good practice to lay down your whole design with white so that the colors will pop.  [Video explanation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4l-g65ph5E).